# QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread: parent's thread:QThread(0x221f650), current thread:QThread(0x23a7950)

Tags: qt, signals-slots, qthread, qobject, qtcpsocket

I am trying to fetch data from device using QTCpSocket (telnet).
After a lot of struggle I felt I overcame one issue that was Qtimer:starttimer can not be started from other thread.

**But,now I have came across another issue which is confusing me a lot.**
I have gone through some post in internet but it's not helping me.
Please go through my code and let me know my mistake

**fdu.cpp**

```
#include "fdu.h"
#include "ui_fdu.h"
#include"fduprocess.h"
fdu::fdu(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::fdu)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    QThread *workerThread =  new QThread;
    fduprocess *worker = new fduprocess;

 qDebug()<< "...goind to fduprocess........";
    workerThread->start();
    worker->_ReconnectionTimerInstance.setSingleShot(true);
    worker->_ReconnectionTimerInstance.start(1000);
    worker->_iStatusPollTimer = startTimer(500);
    worker->moveToThread(workerThread);
    connect(workerThread,SIGNAL(started()),worker,SLOT(tryit()));
    connect(workerThread,SIGNAL(finished()),worker,SLOT(deleteLater()));

}

fdu::~fdu()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

**fduprocess.cpp**

```
#include "fduprocess.h"
#include<QDebug>
#include<QThread>
fduprocess::fduprocess(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{

}

void fduprocess::timerEvent(QTimerEvent *event)
{
    if(event->timerId()== _iStatusPollTimer)
    {

        if(_ClientSocketInstance.state() == QAbstractSocket::ConnectedState)
        {
            _ClientSocketInstance.write("alarmstat\r\n"); //25
             _ClientSocketInstance.write("selectedin\r\n"); // 4
              _ClientSocketInstance.write("sigoutstat\r\n"); //13
           _ClientSocketInstance.write("disablestat\r\n"); //5

           _ClientSocketInstance.write("pwrstat\r\n"); //5

           _ClientSocketInstance.write("siginstat\r\n");//5
        }
    }
}

void fduprocess::tryit()
{
 qDebug()<< "...came inside tryit to tryit.........";
 connect(&_ReconnectionTimerInstance,SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(when_ReconnectionTimer_timeout()));
  qDebug()<< "...conencted to whentimeout.........";
 connect(&_ClientSocketInstance,SIGNAL(connected()), this, SLOT(when_ClientSocketInstance_connected()));
 connect(&_ClientSocketInstance,SIGNAL(disconnected()), this, SLOT(when_ClientSocketInstance_disconnected()));
 connect(&_ClientSocketInstance,SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(when_ClientSocketInstance_readyRead()));
 connect(&_ClientSocketInstance,SIGNAL(error(QAbstractSocket::SocketError)), this, SLOT(when_ClientSocketInstance_error(QAbstractSocket::SocketError)));
 _strIPAddress = "192.168.1.135";
 _usiPort = 23;
  qDebug()<< "...end tryit........";


}

void fduprocess::doOntimeout()
{
    qDebug()<< "................";
}

void fduprocess::when_ReconnectionTimer_timeout()
{
    qDebug()<<"Reconnecting..";
      // qDebug()<< _ClientSocketInstance.children();
        _ClientSocketInstance.connectToHost(_strIPAddress, _usiPort);
}

void fduprocess::when_ClientSocketInstance_connected()
{ qDebug()<<"Connected......";

    _ClientSocketInstance.write("endrun_1");
    _ClientSocketInstance.flush();
    _ClientSocketInstance.write("\n");
    _ClientSocketInstance.write("\n");
    _ClientSocketInstance.write("\n");
    _ClientSocketInstance.flush();

}

void fduprocess::when_ClientSocketInstance_disconnected()
{
    qDebug()<<"Disconnected";
        _ReconnectionTimerInstance.start();
}

void fduprocess::when_ClientSocketInstance_readyRead()
{
    QByteArray get = _ClientSocketInstance.readLine();
    qDebug() << get ;
}

void fduprocess::when_ClientSocketInstance_error(QAbstractSocket::SocketError error)
{

}
```

Any other feedback regarding any other code smells will be highly welcomed 
Please ignore my indentation and naming conventions,since I am in my learning curve.
**Here is the console output :**

```
...goind to fduprocess........
...came inside tryit to tryit.........
...conencted to whentimeout.........
...end tryit........
Reconnecting..
QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread.
(Parent is QTcpSocket(0x609250), parent's thread is QThread(0x221f650), current thread is QThread(0x23a7950)
QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread.
(Parent is QTcpSocket(0x609250), parent's thread is QThread(0x221f650), current thread is QThread(0x23a7950)
QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread.
(Parent is QTcpSocket(0x609250), parent's thread is QThread(0x221f650), current thread is QThread(0x23a7950)
```

Comment: Please show he code (with some context) that creates the `QTcpSocket` (the variable `_ClientSocketInstance` I'm guessing?).  My guess would be that you initialize it without a parent object meaning that it stays on the main thread even after its \`containing' `fduprocess` has been moved to the new thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create `worker`, the object and all its members are created in the main thread. Then, you move `worker` to its own thread, which moves all its children QObjects. All slots in `worker` will now be executed on this new thread.

From `fduprocess` constructor, it looks like you don't give a parent to your socket (`_ClientSocketInstance`). That means the socket is not moved to the same thread as the worker but stays in the main thread, which gives this warning when you use it from a slot. If you pass `this` to `_ClientSocketInstance` constructor to make it a child of `worker`, it will automatically be moved to the same thread as `worker` and the warning should disappear.

Comment: Thanx ! I moved  worker->_ClientSocketInstance.moveToThread(workerThread);
    worker->_ReconnectionTimerInstance.moveToThread(workerThread); & it solved my issue